# .net native extension for node.js

Tags: c#, c++, .net, node.js, visual-c++

I want to make use of .net dlls in node.js. Does that mean I need to make those dlls available with c/c++ using 'clr hosting', a la

- [.NET Framework 4 Hosting Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380851.aspx) or
- [Hosting the Common Language Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/9x0wh2z3.aspx)

<strike>Unfortunately the example [Creating a nodejs native .Net extension](https://github.com/saary/node.net/) over at github was a bit of a disappointment, just scroll down to the last step</strike>

> Change the "Common Language Runtime Support" option to No Common Language RunTime Support

and you know what I mean. Correction to do that article justice: It suggests to change that option to "No Common Language RunTime Support" **only for the file `SharpAddon.cpp`**, so other .cpp-files you add will have CLR support enabled (the default for a CLR project), which means you can in fact use .net dlls from those other .cpp files.

This question is actually a duplicate of [Using a .NET DLL in Node.js / serverside javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653433), which was written at a time when there was not even a native Windows port of node, so times might have changed, although google makes me doubt it.

Comment: It's hard to tell if it's being actively developed/maintained, but if you don't need 100% compatibility with node.js, this looks interesting: http://newcome.wordpress.com/2010/05/08/node-net-node-js-implemented-in-javascript-on-the-net-runtime/ .

Comment: @reuben Thanks for the link, but for the problem at hand I want to have the most stable and performing implementation possible, so I guess I'm stuck with the original, which is being developed at a really fast pace and is also getting steam on the Windows platform recently.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update**: node-gyp can do the manual steps below automatically when the `binding.gyp` file is setup properly. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38690005/709537) for this simplified procedure.

---

It turned out to be rather easy. After struggling with CLR hosting and getting data in and out of the host for a while, it turns out **you can actually enable /clr for your node extension no problem** (so far). Here's how:

- follow the instructions on http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html to generate the project files
- open the generated .sln in Visual Studio (I'm on VS 2010) and enable /clr in the project settings
- now it probably won't build and you have to let the - in this case actually quite helpful - error messages guide you to the flags that conflict with /clr

The flags that I had to change to make it work:

- disable /EHsc (C++ exceptions)
- disable /RTC1 and /RTCsu
- Release: change /MT to /MD
- Debug: change /MTd to /MDd
- Release: change /GR- to /GR

Then you can mix managed and unmanaged code like this, referencing your .net dlls.

```
#pragma managed

#using <managed.dll>

void callManaged()
{
    managed::Class1^ c1 = gcnew managed::Class1();
    System::String^ result = c1->Echo("hola");
    System::Console::WriteLine("It works: " + result);
}

#pragma unmanaged

Handle<Value> Method(const Arguments& args) {
  HandleScope scope;
  callManaged();
  return scope.Close(String::New("world"));
}
```

**Update** Just discovered this link with an easy https://web.archive.org/web/20170702003703/http://joseoncode.com/2012/04/10/writing-your-first-native-module-for-node-dot-js-on-windows/

Comment: +1 nice. Now I have one more way to write native extension for node.js and enjoy power of .Net

Comment: @Viet It should be kept in mind though that crossing the native / CLR boundary incurs a cost every time you do it - and that depends on how often *native* calls into *.net* (or the other way around). How high that cost is, I haven't measured yet.

Comment: Thanks for the note. Once you run the program through the profiler, you may want to share the findings too, like on your blog

Comment: The link is no longer active, can use "wayback machine". https://web.archive.org/web/20170702003703/http://joseoncode.com/2012/04/10/writing-your-first-native-module-for-node-dot-js-on-windows/

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like edge.js is the new answer from the author of iisnode:

[Edge.js](http://tjanczuk.github.com/edge/#/) supports using C# and .NET instead of writing native node.js extensions

Answer (score 0):

These days, there's [cmake-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cmake-js) and [node-addon-api](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api) that make things both easier, plus the ABI of node-addon-api means the module does not need to be recompiled when used with a newer version of Node.js.

See this answer for a short tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54339042/709537