# Node.js extension for .net

Tags: node.js

Attempting to use node-sharp - https://github.com/anodejs/node-sharp to load some existing .net assemblies I have. Have not been able to get it to work so far - only seem to get a "The specified procedure could not be found".

So I attempted to start with a simpler example and followed this guide - http://coderesearchlabs.com/articles/BNWCA.pdf. Same result.

I'm running in Windows 64 with 32 bit version of Node.js installed version 0.8.16.

Error stack trace -

```
> require("./Sharp").hello
Error: The specified procedure could not be found.
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\Sharp.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:485:11)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at repl:1:2
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:109:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:248:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:200:10)
> console.log('Version: ' + process.version);
Version: v0.8.16
undefined
>
```

Source is

```
#pragma comment(lib, "node")

#include <node.h>
#include <v8.h>

using namespace node;
using namespace v8;

extern "C" void NODE_EXTERN init (Handle<Object> target)

{

HandleScope scope;

target->Set(String::New("hello"), String::New("world"));

}

NODE_MODULE(test, init)
```

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11389044/709537 I was running an x64 node.js, but it should work just as well for x86.

Comment: Tx for the link - that helped a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the module name matches what was passed to `NODE_MODULE`:

```
NODE_MODULE(test, init)  // => `test.node`
NODE_MODULE(Sharp, init) // => `Sharp.node`
```

Also, as that guide appears to be for Node 0.6.x with 0.8.0 [released](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/06/25/node-v0-8-0/) after it, you may find the [Addons](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) and [node-gyp](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp) documentation useful for Node 0.8 development.

Comment: Tx - this got me on the right track. The major issue was changes with v0.8 versus what the samples were written in.