# How to call functions in a C# dll file from a node.js file

Tags: c#, node.js, function, dll, wrapper

**I created a C# dll file that contains functions that returns some values, and I am trying to call these functions from a node.js file to get those values. Please how do I go about this?

Comment: that works with C and C++ not C# tho, at least to my understanding

Answer (score 3):

I believe the [Edge.js - Run .NET and Node.js code in-process on Windows, macOS, and Linux](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) is what you need.

By using `Edge.js`, we can write the following JavaScript codes that invoke existing C# programs.

```js
var clrMethod = edge.func({
    assemblyFile: 'My.Edge.Samples.dll',
    typeName: 'Samples.FooBar.MyType',
    methodName: 'MyMethod' // This must be Func<object,Task<object>>
});
```

Or

```js
var clrMethod = edge.func('My.Edge.Samples.dll');
```

Or

```js
var add7 = edge.func(require('path').join(__dirname, 'add7.csx'));
```

The above three sample codes are all copy/pasted from their GitHub home page.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for how to implement a native code nodejs addon is here: [Node.js v0.12.7 Addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) and there are numerous examples included in that documentation.

More specific discussion of doing an addon in C# here: [Using a .NET DLL in Node.js / serverside javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653433/using-a-net-dll-in-node-js-serverside-javascript) and [.net native extension for node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257690/net-native-extension-for-node-js)

I can imagine it gets a bit tricky trying to hook up two garbage collected languages since automatic garbage collection probably isn't completely possible both ways.

Comment: Thanks! I saw something earlier about edge.js, do you know anything about it?

Comment: @user2560413 - I don't know anything about it.